# Looping through multiple SQL queries

Tags: php, sql

I have an SQL table of tens of thousand of orders, each one is from around 100 different companies.  I want to do a total for each company on an admin web page.

Am I supposed to loop and do 100 queries (one for each company) - eg 'SELECT SUM(order_amount) FROM orders WHERE company = XXX' or do one query to show all orders to loop through them and add each order to an array key of a company, eg  company_array[company] += order_amount

Comment: It kind of depends on your table structure, but I would usually do this sort of thing in a single query with a [`GROUP BY` modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

Comment: SQL is a set-based langauge, you rarely need to *loop*. You can easily accomplish this in a single query but without details of your tables and sample data, we can't show you.

Comment: Thank you - the GroupBy thing looks like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

With a structure like this :

```
companies
--------------
company_id
company_name

orders
--------------
order_id
order_company # Foreign key to companies.company_id
order_amount
```

You can do an unique SQL request like that :

```
SELECT ALL company_name, SUM(order_amount) AS company_amount
FROM orders INNER JOIN companies ON order_company = company_id
GROUP BY company_name
```

With PHP :

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT ALL company_name, SUM(order_amount) AS company_amount
    FROM orders INNER JOIN companies ON order_company = company_id
    GROUP BY company_name
    SQL;
$result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();
// Now you can loop $result
print_r($result);
```